# Animated Grab Handle For Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, bottom-sheet

**Background:**

I have a bottom sheet within an android fragment which I wish to have a grab handle on. The bottom sheet is always showing and can be expanded upwards, I beleive this means it can never be in a STATE_HIDDEN state. To be clear, this is a constraint layout with a BottomSheetBehaviour. The grab handle is just an image view.

I would like the handle to be animated in the following way:

- It should start as a flat bar indicating that it can be grabbed and
  the card can expand.
- When the bottom sheet is expanded fully to fill
  the page the handle should lool like a chevron pointing downwards
  indicating the card can be dragged downwards to it's previously
  collapsed state.

**My Question:**

How do I animate a clean transition from one SVG to another which reacts based on the amount the bottom sheet has been expanded?

**What I have so far:**

Fragment:

I have the following code in my fragment which I have played around with and so I know this works in terms of changing the UI based on the sliding or the state. If I set the svg to be the down arrow in the collapsed state (not really what I want) when I slide up the arrow slowly flattens, thins and disappears.

```
val bottomSheetCallback = object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
      //
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
      //             ***Put some animation/transition here - this is my failing attempt***
      //                val grabHandle = binding.myBottomSheet.grabHandle
      //                val degrees = 90.0f * slideOffset
      //                grabHandle.animate().rotationX(degrees)
          
            }
        }

        val sheet: View = binding.myBottomSheet.root
        val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(sheet)
        behaviour.addBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback)
    }
```

Bar SVG:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="32dp"
    android:height="4dp"
    android:viewportWidth="32"
    android:viewportHeight="4">
  <path
      android:pathData="M2,0L30,0A2,2 0,0 1,32 2L32,2A2,2 0,0 1,30 4L2,4A2,2 0,0 1,0 2L0,2A2,2 0,0 1,2 0z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:fillAlpha="0.2"
      android:fillType="nonZero"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
</vector>
```

Chevron SVG:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="35dp"
    android:height="12dp"
    android:viewportWidth="35"
    android:viewportHeight="12">
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="0.2"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fillType="nonZero"
        android:pathData="M33.4565,3.8194L17.3125,11.1996L1.1685,3.8194C0.1639,3.3602 -0.2782,2.1735 0.181,1.169C0.6184,0.2122 1.7156,-0.2343 2.6869,0.122L2.8315,0.1815L17.313,6.8025L31.7935,0.1815C32.7502,-0.2558 33.8721,0.1243 34.3735,1.0293L34.444,1.169C34.8813,2.1257 34.5012,3.2476 33.5962,3.749L33.4565,3.8194Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
</vector>
```

I also managed to make an animated vector file, but I have no idea if this is required this currently has a "duration" so I haven't managed to get this to react to any UI input yet:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="35dp"
            android:height="12dp"
            android:viewportWidth="35"
            android:viewportHeight="12">
            <path
                android:name="path"
                android:pathData="M 3.5 4 L 31.5 4 C 32.03 4 32.539 4.21 32.914 4.585 C 33.289 4.96 33.5 5.469 33.5 6 C 33.5 6.53 33.289 7.039 32.914 7.414 C 32.539 7.789 32.03 8 31.5 8 L 3.5 8 C 2.97 8 2.461 7.789 2.086 7.414 C 1.711 7.039 1.5 6.53 1.5 6 C 1.5 5.469 1.711 4.96 2.086 4.585 C 2.461 4.21 2.97 4 3.5 4"
                android:fillColor="#FFFFFF
"
                android:fillAlpha="0.2"
                android:strokeWidth="1"/>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="200"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 3.5 8 C 2.97 8 2.461 7.789 2.086 7.414 C 1.711 7.039 1.5 6.53 1.5 6 C 1.5 5.469 1.711 4.96 2.086 4.585 C 2.461 4.21 2.97 4 3.5 4 L 18.455 4 L 31.5 4 C 32.03 4 32.539 4.21 32.914 4.585 C 33.289 4.96 33.5 5.469 33.5 6 C 33.5 6.53 33.289 7.039 32.914 7.414 C 32.542 7.786 32.039 7.996 31.514 8 C 31.51 8 31.505 8 31.5 8 L 18.455 8 L 3.5 8"
                android:valueTo="M 1.169 3.819 C 0.666 3.59 0.305 3.178 0.126 2.699 C -0.053 2.219 -0.049 1.671 0.181 1.169 C 0.618 0.212 1.716 -0.234 2.687 0.122 C 2.735 0.142 2.783 0.162 2.832 0.181 L 17.313 6.803 L 31.794 0.181 C 32.75 -0.256 33.872 0.124 34.373 1.029 C 34.397 1.076 34.42 1.122 34.444 1.169 C 34.881 2.126 34.501 3.248 33.596 3.749 C 33.55 3.772 33.503 3.796 33.456 3.819 C 33.456 3.819 33.456 3.819 33.456 3.819 L 17.313 11.2 L 1.169 3.819"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

I know I'm somewhat close, but have no idea where to go next...

I found an example of what I want it's the first animated example under Samples on this website, I just cannot use that library:
https://androidexample365.com/easy-way-to-make-bottom-sheet-with-animation/